# ESXi vDS multiple LAG

Tags: networking, vmware-esxi, etherchannel

Currently network design is 2 Switches and each ESXi host has 4 NICs. 2 NICs are connected to Switch #1 and 2 NICs are connected to Switch #2. As this are different Switches it’s not possible to create etherchannel with the 4 NICs. So best I could do on switch side is 2 different etherchannels.

vDS has multiple Portgroups. Currently it’s using one active LAG from 2 NICs on Switch #1. Idea would be to active 2 active LAGs (with the remaining NICs on Switch #2) on the same vDS but that’s not possible (at least I was not allowed to create).

What would be the best configuration to achieve both LAGs active for the same Portgroup? Unfortunately those are only 1G connections and would be good to have all 4 active with teaming. Even if it’s 2x2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you can do what you want to do sorry - as you'd just end up with mac-flapping. Also you say "As this are different Switches it’s not possible to create etherchannel with the 4 NICs" - what switches are they? you mention etherchannel, presumably that means you're using Cisco kit, if so can you not use a VSS link or VPC between them?

Comment: Switches are Cisco 3750X. Not sure if that is possible. Not something I'm used to.

Comment: Ah yeah, they're pretty old now I guess.

Comment: Well in that case there is no way to take advantage of the 4 NICs active. I guess.